# Android Studio Kotlin: Why my Button continually causes crashes when I clicked it

Tags: android, kotlin, voice, voice-recording, kotlin-android

i am making a voice recorder activity, but when i press the button to play the recorded voice it give me a message "unable to play the audio file: /storage/emulated//0/recorded_audio.mp3: open..."

Here's the code:

```
val hintBar: TextView = findViewById(R.id.hint_bar)
        val filePath = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath}/recorded_audio.mp3"
        val outputFile = File(filePath)
        recordingStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.recording_status)
        startRecordingButton = findViewById(R.id.start_recording)
        stopRecordingButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_recording)

        mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mediaRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        mediaRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        mediaRecorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        mediaRecorder?.setOutputFile(outputFile.path)


        startRecordingButton.setOnClickListener {

            mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
                setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
                setOutputFile(filePath)
                setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

                try {
                    mediaRecorder?.prepare()
                    mediaRecorder?.start()
                    recordingStatusTextView.text = "Recording..." // updating the status

                } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                hintBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        stopRecordingButton.setOnClickListener{
            try {
                mediaRecorder?.stop()
                mediaRecorder?.release()
                recordingStatusTextView.text = "Recording Stopped" // updating the status

            } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            hintBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }



        lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
        val playButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.play_button)
        playButton.setOnClickListener {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath)
                mediaPlayer.prepare()
                mediaPlayer.start()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // Show a toast message to the user
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to play the audio file: " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("MediaPlayer", e.toString())
            }

        }
```

it should just play the voice that i just recorded but it's showing the "unable to play the audio file: /storage/emulated//0/recorded_audio.mp3: open..." message

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the error that you echo here: `Log.e("MediaPlayer", e.toString())`

Comment: sorry i am a beginner here, but how can i add the full stacktrace?

Comment: first make sure your recording of audio functionality is working and output file exists 
Also as it is not mentioned anywhere about permission handling so make sure you have added permission in manifest and ask at runtime

Comment: If you run your application via Android Studio you can use the bottom-tab 'logcat' to output text. Search for the 'mediaplayer' tag and copy the message!

Comment: Please make sure you are asking the required permissions before trying to access the file.